# Why can I only deploy Github Pages live sites on certain repositories even though all of them have the same settings?

Tags: github, github-pages

So I went through the official github docs -> Creating (https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site) & Publishing (https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/changing-the-visibility-of-your-github-pages-site)

For some reason on certain repositories it does not allow me to publish [no option to publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKSHV.png) https://mrcppv.github.com/ZendzceStudy/ (404 error) but on others it allows me to just fine [Publishing available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g4Ea.png) https://mrcppv.github.io/htmlADVprj1/

The issue seems intermittent due to the fact that I was able to see the option and publish a completely different repo, but then when I unpublished it the option disappeared!

does anyone know what could the issue be? it seems totally random, one repo I unpublished and then the option to publish it again disappeared. I followed all of the instructions in the documentation and the settings for both repositories are exactly the same. Its beyond me. If anyone has any ideas please feel free to add. (yes they are both public, and both contain an index.html file.

I read the documentation thoroughly  [I did not use jakyl for either of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej8G9.png) I saw other people had similar questions but for them it wasnt publishing at all. For me one is, one is not.